# Show that the sequence $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}$ converge toward 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show that the sequence $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}$ converge toward $L = 0$.

We have :

$$
\begin{align}
  |u_n - L| = \left| \left( \sqrt{n+1)} - \sqrt{n} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} \right) \right| = \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} \right| \leq \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+
1}} \right|
\end{align}
$$

For every $\epsilon > 0$, by the Archimedean property, we can take

$$
N \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} - 1
$$

Such that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq N$,

$$
  |u_n - L| \leq \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}} \leq \epsilon
$$

Eventually, we can write :

$$
  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = 0
$$

Is it a correct way to prove that the sequence converge ?

Comment: First line of first display is lacking a pair of parentheses.

Comment: essentially yes, you can make like easier for yourself by using $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ as the upper bound

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show $b_n=\sqrt[k]{n+1}-\sqrt[k]{n}$ converges towards $0$ for all $k \geq 2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572032/show-b-n-sqrtkn1-sqrtkn-converges-towards-0-for-all-k-geq-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very good. You are missing some parentheses, as was mentioned. I would rephrase your application of the Archimedean property. Generally it refers to your $N$ as being an integer. So, you would need $$N\ge \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} - 1.$$ Also you are using $N$ for two different things, just use $\mathbb{N}$ (`\mathbb{N}`) or $\mathbb{Z}^+$ (`\mathbb{Z}^+`) for the set of natural numbers. I don't know your prefference but I like to end with a statement such as "since for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $|u_n|<\epsilon$, by definition,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n} = 0."$$
Very good work.