# Show that $(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}$ converges to zero.

Tags: real-analysis

Let sequence $x_n=(n+1)^{1/3}$ and sequence $y_n=n^{1/3}$.

Basically, I'm trying to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} | x_n-y_n | =0,$$

which is intuitively true.

After some attempts, I find it hard to bound $(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}$ anything useful. Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: Use the identity $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434089/limit-of-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrt3n1-sqrt3n/3434097#3434097

Comment: Here is one [for all cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572032/show-b-n-sqrtkn1-sqrtkn-converges-towards-0-for-all-k-geq-2/).